# subfigure.sty and acronym.sty not found

Tags: errors, installing

After my old computer broke down, i have installed latex again on my new computer with 64-bit windows 7. However, when I try to compile a simple example that alaways worked before, i always get the error 'subfigure.sty' not found. When I remove the subfigure package, the compiler instead complains on the acronym.sty. I have updated the MIkTex but it didn't help. Does anybody know why this error appears?

Comment: If you installed the basic MikTeX then you do not have all packages yet. You may use texniccenter as an editor and there are problems reported with installing packages on-the-fly with this editor. You can open the miktex package browser and install them manually or you open your code in the TexWorks editor which is automatically installed with MiKTeX. This editor has no problems to install the packages for you

Comment: And [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: thansks for your answers and comments, unfortunatelly nothing worked. I tried to install the packages manually and now the files subfigure.sty and acronym.sty are there but the compiler still cannot find them. I'm using Texmaker but I also tried with TeXworks. I've also tried reinstalling everything. Maybe I missed something during installation, is it enough just to run a straight forward installation of MikTex and TexMaker or is there something else that should be set. This worked perfectly on my old computer with WindowsXP but now I reinstalled everything on a new computer with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

In MikTeX you can chose if you want to have new packages installed automatically or manually. To enable automatic installation, open the MikTeX settings dialogue (under `Maintenance (Admin)` select `Settings (Admin)`) and change the setting `Install missing packages on-the-fly`to `yes`. Using this setting together with TeXnicCenter works for me.

[image: MikTex Settings]

Answer (score 1):

As I do not know how did you install the packages manually, first of all, I would recommend you to take a look into the **MikTeX Package Manager (Admin)**. If you would be able to find them there, it means that MiKTeX knows about them and the problem is somewhere else.

[image: package manager]

Next, you can **edit your Question** and put some **minimal work example (MWE)** of your latex code you are trying to compile. Then the community can be helpful more.

Comment: I agree, typically package installation via the package manager (or on-the-fly installation as suggested in user21511's answer) should work. In case manual installation is needed (which should _not_ be the case for `subfigure` and `acronym`!), we have a popular question for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows